# Attach an OnChange handler to existing textbox control NSIS

Tags: installation, controls, onchange, nsis, nsdialogs

I'm trying to attach an onchange event handler to the existing Install directory textbox in NSIS. However, it never seems to trigger. Any ideas how I can do this?

```
GetDlgItem $TextControl $HWNDPARENT 1019
GetFunctionAddress $R0 MYFUNCTION
nsDialogs::OnChange  $TextControl $R0
```

I've used Resource hacker to get the control ID and I added the above code to a MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_SHOW before displaying the MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY.

Any help on getting a function to trigger on an already existing control would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nsDialogs `On*` callbacks only works on nsDialogs custom pages.

You can use the [`.onVerifyInstDir`](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Reference/.onVerifyInstDir) function callback if you need to inspect the `$InstDir` variable on the directory page.

Comment: Amazing! Works a treat. Thanks for your help. :)